# How to construct a lens of 2 properties?

Tags: f#, lenses

Suppose I have a record like this:

```ml
type Order = | Order

type OrderBook = 
  {
    PrimaryOrderID : Guid
    Orders : Map<Guid, Order>
  }
```

I would like to do nested updates using lenses.

Here are the [optics type aliases](https://github.com/xyncro/aether/blob/ffcef99f54a6d79a6a4a580f0db1fc059e821fa0/src/Aether/Aether.fs#L7-L13):

```ml
/// Lens from 'a -> 'b.
type Lens<'a,'b> =
    ('a -> 'b) * ('b -> 'a -> 'a)

/// Prism from 'a -> 'b.
type Prism<'a,'b> =
    ('a -> 'b option) * ('b -> 'a -> 'a)
```

I would like to construct a lens for the *primary order*. This may be `None` if the primary order does not exist in the `Orders` map.

Here is what I came up with:

```ml
module Optics = 

  let primaryOrder_ : Prism<OrderBook, Order> = 
    let get =
      fun orderBook ->
        orderBook.Orders 
        |> Map.tryFind orderBook.PrimaryOrderID
    
    let set =
      fun primaryOrder orderBook ->
        {
          orderBook with
            Orders = 
              orderBook.Orders
              |> Map.add orderBook.PrimaryOrderID primaryOrder
        }

    get, set
```

However, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to define this in terms of `primaryOrderID_` and `orders_` lenses?

```ml
module Optics = 

  let primaryOrderID_ : Lens<OrderBook, Guid> = 
    (fun x -> x.PrimaryOrderID), (fun v x -> { x with PrimaryOrderID = v })

  let orders_ : Lens<OrderBook, Map<Guid, Order>> =
    (fun x -> x.Orders), (fun v x -> { x with Orders = v })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on optics, but I think the simple answer has to be no, because neither of the field-level lenses will call `Map.tryFind` or `Map.add`, like your high-level `primaryOrder_` lens does.

This seems to be due to an implied type-level invariant: the `Orders` map must always contain an entry for the primary order. Since `OrderBook` as currently written doesn't enforce this, things could break if the invariant isn't honored in client code.

I think if you address this underlying issue first, the optics will then be easier to figure out. One simple approach would be to define `OrderBook` like this instead:

```ml
type OrderBook =
    {
        PrimaryOrder : Order   // the entire order, not just its ID
        OtherOrders : Map<Guid, Order>
    }
```

The `primaryOrder_` lens would then be trivial, but the actual best answer will probably depend on your use case. (Note that this is similar to [`NonEmptyMap`](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/reference/fsharpplus-data-nonemptymap.html) in FSharpPlus, with the assumption that `Order` has its own `ID : Guid` field.)

Comment: The primary order is an option. It may not exist in the map